# xamarin web API authentication

Tags: authentication, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am very new to Xamarin and mobile development and I am currently involved in developing a sample application with authentication. We are using our internal Web API service to authenticate and can someone guide me how to proceed in this case. I am planning to use MvvmCross framework in my development. I am NOT using Xamarin forms and using the platform specific project for Android as part of my initial development. Any help really appreciated.

Here is the sample code I am using to call my WebAPI

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutAsync<T>(string url,T content)
        {

             using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
          //  using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
                var address = string.Format("{0}{1}", WebService.BaseUrl, url);
                var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await client.PutAsync(new System.Uri(address), httpContent);
                return response;
            }
        }`enter code here`
```

> I was able to call a sample get request using http but failing on
>
> > https

request. I am testing on android 4.4 Kit kat device

```
System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler handler = new NativeMessageHandler(false,true);

.Net.Http.HttpClient client = (handler == null) ? new System.Net.Http.HttpClient() :new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler(false,true));
result = client.GetAsync("https://httpbin.org/ip");
                var stream = await result.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: I just noticed It works when I test my PCL class using a test project but no response when I run it from my Android device.

Comment: No response can't be. There must be an exception or something other that indicates whats wrong. You are not using `address = "http://localhost/..."` or domething like that, or!?

Comment: Yes, I am using my local service pointing to localhost endpoint. like below

http://localhost/xxxxxxx/api/security/login/

Comment: localhost on your phone is your phone. The server runs on your desktop pc or somewhere else. so you have to use the correct IP like `http://192.168.x.x./...`

Comment: i tried it but not luck. I also tried with our service endpoint which deployed on our company domain and still same issue..

Comment: But as I said... there must be some exception or the response has a statuscode that indicates the error. If the method does not return, maybe a timeout will happen, so just wait a bit longer

Comment: I just re re-referenced all the nuget packages in my PCL project and seems like its working. Thank you Sevn-Michale Stude for your comments and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my code which I got it worked.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using ModernHttpClient;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
namespace App.Portable
{
    public interface IHttpService
    {
        Task<T> ReadContentAsync<T>(Task<HttpResponseMessage> response);
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url);
        Task<string> PutAsync<T>(string url,T content);
    }

    public class HttpService : IHttpService
    {

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException();
        }
        public async Task<string> PutAsync<T>(string url,T content)
        {
            HttpMessageHandler handler = new NativeMessageHandler(false,true);
            HttpClient client = (handler == null) ? new HttpClient() :new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler(false,true));
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
                var address = string.Format("{0}{1}", WebService.BaseUrl, url);
                var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response =  client.PutAsync(new System.Uri(address), httpContent);
                var stream = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return stream;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your service supports OAuth (what I'd recommend for apps), you can use the Xamarin.Auth library to Authenticate your users. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Auth/

Here is a tutorial how to use it: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/

Comment: I am not using OAuth. I tried to get the help from the following post http://www.sylapse.com/xamarin/mobile-rest-client-with-xamarin/
I tried to call the service exactly mentioned in this but my service request is not goingthrough. See my updated post with sample code I am using